# Packaging ROS with homebrew

Tags: ros, homebrew, bloom-release, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there plans or have there been attempts to package ROS as homebrew formulas in a similar way to the debs on Ubuntu?

**Edit:** For future reference: With pointers from William a proof of concept has been created, but there are a few issues that need to be addressed: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/254#issuecomment-37401069

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130346/packaging-ros-with-homebrew/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have looked to do it for a long time now, but I have never had the time to setup everything. For now, all the time I can afford to spend on it is to keep it building from source on OS X.

From my perspective, the main challenges to getting this working are as follows:

- Generating Homebrew formulae for packages using bloom
- Setting up a CI system on OS X which has a clean starting point for each build
- Building bottles, pushing them to some storage (like download.ros.org/bottles), and updating the formula which uses the bottle

I think that generating Formulae for packages is the only sustainable way to approach this problem. There are nearly 800 packages in Hydro and 200+ in desktop-full. Packaging them by hand is error prone and unmaintainable. So coming up with a bloom generator for the formulae would be crucial. I started that work, but didn't get very far at all:

https://github.com/wjwwood/bloom_homebrew

The CI system for OS X has also been a challenge. I spent some time trying to setup a diskimage with COW for OS X which would behave like chroot/pbuilder for linux but ran into a lot of issues. The other thing I tried was using a VM and snapshots through a Python API, but that required Parallels which is not free and was slow. The Homebrew guys just clear `/usr/local` with `git clean -fdx` between builds for their "homebrew brewbot" system (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/homebrew/brew-test-bot). I believe we (OSRF) are setting up a similar setup using jenkins on our build farms:

http://build.osrfoundation.org/view/SDFormat/job/sdformat-any-devel-homebrew-amd64/

If that is successful, I might try to use it for packaging ROS.

Finally, for bottle support (which would be awesome), we would need to also build each formula with the `--build-bottle` option, create the bottle, upload it somewhere (like download.ros.org/bottles) and then update the formula again, probably pushing the formula to `https://github.com/ros/homebrew-hydro/`.

So I have looked into it before, but as always progress on this is subject to my free time, which is in pretty low supply at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-19**:
As always thanks for the comprehensive answer. At least the current state of affairs is out there now. I don't think I will manage to do it just now, but maybe me or otgera can work towards it in the future. I fully agree that automatic bottle creation is a must. I can wounder if we can get support

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-02-19**:
from the homebrew guys for things like CI and bottle creation. However they might not be happy about 800+ incoming formulae. In any case publishing at least the core packages of a base install would be a gigantic leap for OSX support.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-09**:
Upstream ticket to track progress on this: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/254